# Tile Color not being set in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live-tile

I have upgraded my app to WP 8.1. Unfortunately, when I create a Tile for my app, it's not using the specific color I've set in the `Package.appxmanifest`

```
<m3:VisualElements DisplayName="xxxxx" Square150x150Logo="Assets\SquareTile150x150.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Description="xxxxx" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#00bbff">
```

I've tried to use transparent background and my color in the png-files, but it's still using the custom backgroundcolor which I've set in my configuration on my phone.
How can I use the color #00bbff when I create the Tile of my app?
The app-symbol in my WMAppManifest.xml has the background 00bbff, the tile images in WMAppManifest.xml have a transparent background.

Comment: Does it work if you set BackgroundColor="transparent" or a color like red?

Comment: This is odd. In my app I used to have the color set to purple but I changed it to transparent. Now when I try and change it back to purple it won't work.

Comment: I didn't really care now and just uploaded my app in the store. Luckily, it works now normally. Probably it doesn't work while I just run it on my phone...!? (It used to work normally, but now that I'm using VS2015 it changed ..)